# Insert or Update with Play-Slick

Tags: scala, play-slick

Is there any API in `Play-Slick` where we can do insert or update at same time. We are using Play-Slick 0.8.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. Play-Slick 0.8.0 is based on Slick 2.1.0 which does not have an upsert function.

EDIT - I stand corrected, there is a `insertOrUpdate` function.